# google app engine flexible environment deploy fails with file not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, gcloud

I am trying to deploy `google app engine's flexible environment`. Inside my `appengine` folder I have my `app.yaml` and `Dockerfile`. The Dockerfile has a custom entry point that requires a file in the root folder:

`ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/api-server.jar","server","api-server.yaml"]`

**ERROR:**

```
[INFO] ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
[INFO] Application startup error:
[INFO] Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File api-server.yaml not found
```

**Question:** From what directory does the entry point command run? What is the appropriate path I need to supply to find the file?

**Directory Tree:**

```
api-server/
-api-server.yaml<br>
-src/main/appengine/<br>
--app.yaml<br>
--Dockerfile<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up changing my Dockerfile like so:

`ADD api-server.yaml /api-server.yaml
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/api-server.jar","server","/api-server.yaml"]`

This is not ideal, but it works.

Comment: This is expected, since a file will not be added to the filesystem of the container unless added using the ADD directive.